# Find value in JSON HTTP response

Tags: java, groovy, httpresponse

I want to get the value of city from the below httpResponse (JSON Response) where fruit is Apple. I am unable to find a way to add this condition to my groovy script.

```
{
    "userInformation": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Location": "India"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "fruit": "Apple",
            "color": "Red",
            "city": "New Delhi",
            "luckyNumber": 10
        },
        {
            "fruit": "Banana",
            "color": "yellow",
            "city": "Goa",
            "luckyNumber": 12
         }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JsonSlurper` is what you need. It parses JSON object to a plain `Map` which can be then easily navigated to find the desired value.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
    "userInformation": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Location": "India"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "fruit": "Apple",
            "color": "Red",
            "city": "New Delhi",
            "luckyNumber": 10
        },
        {
            "fruit": "Banana",
            "color": "yellow",
            "city": "Goa",
            "luckyNumber": 12
         }
   ]
}
'''

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

slurped.details.find { it.fruit == 'Apple' }?.city
```

Comment: Hey Opal, thank you for answering. What if my httpResponse is a map. In order to pass it to JsonSlurper.parseText, i would need to convert it to String first. How can I do that? Also, What if i have two conditions where fruit == Apple and luckyNumber == 10. I am somehow getting null response.

Comment: @ComplexData if it's a `Map` the you go straight on with searching.

Comment: @ComplexData if this answer has helped you, please accept it.